Shortcut to generate setters with `this` as return type
Let's say I have a class HomeWork and is annotated with @Builder
@Data
@Builder
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
class HomeWork {
    List<Question> questions;
    double totalMarks;

    double receivedMarks;
    boolean passed;
}

I can create the instance of HomeWork using builder:
...

HomeWork homeWork = HomeWork.builder()
.questions(List.of(questions))
.totalMarks(100.0)
.build()

Now if I have to update the receivedMarks and passed properties then I will have to call the setters of them like this:
homeWork.setReceivedMarks(85.0);
homeWork.setPassed(true);

This is fine but could be better, if I had setters which would return this so we could chain the setters:
public HomeWork setReceivedMarks(double receivedMarks) {
   this.receivedMarks = receivedMarks;
   return this;
}
...

setReceivedMarks(85).setPassed(true);

So I wanted to know if there is any shortcut way to generate such setters in Intellij IDE? If not then is there any other way to chain the setters?

You can use Lombok annotation Accessors, which accept parameter chain=true which will result in setters returning this variable.
Example:
@Data
@Builder
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Accessors(chain = true)
class HomeWork {
     ...

}


Thank you so much, something like this what exactly I was looking for

Go to Code -> Generate (command + N on macOS), choose "Setter"

In the dialog that appears, choose "Builder" as the template:

If you don't have this template for some reason, you can add it by clicking on the "..." button,

The template is:
#set($paramName = $helper.getParamName($field, $project))
public ##
#if($field.modifierStatic)
static void ##
#else
  $classSignature ##
#end
set$StringUtil.capitalizeWithJavaBeanConvention($StringUtil.sanitizeJavaIdentifier($helper.getPropertyName($field, $project)))($field.type $paramName) {
#if ($field.name == $paramName)
  #if (!$field.modifierStatic)
  this.##
  #else
    $classname.##
  #end
#end
$field.name = $paramName;
#if(!$field.modifierStatic)
return this;
#end
}


Thank you so much, It is really nice to know we have more control over auto generated boilerplate code, will use it too, but for my this use case @Accessors(chain = true) seem to be working fine, thank you again for something new.

@prince Ah, I didn't notice that you were using lombok.
